# Find an object inside an object

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I am currently trying to access an object and its properties but I can't seem to find a way to get objects that are not the first items in their respective children array. It can find numbers only if they're first in the array, but I think that I did the wrong thing in my function, and I am not quite sure how to fix it. What could be my mistakes and how do I fix this?

Here is the tree:

```
{
    name: "One",
    ids: {
        id: 1,
        level: 0
    },
    children: [
        {
            name: "Two",
            ids: {
                id: 2,
                level: 1
            },
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Three",
                    ids: {
                        id: 3,
                        level: 2
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "Five",
                            ids: {
                                id: 5,
                                level: 3
                            },
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: "Eight",
                                    ids: {
                                        id: 8,
                                        level: 4
                                    },
                                    children: []
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Nine",
                                    ids: {
                                        id: 9,
                                        level: 4
                                    },
                                    children: []
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Ten",
                                    ids: {
                                        id: 10,
                                        level: 4
                                    },
                                    children: []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Four",
                    ids: {
                        id: 4,
                        level: 2
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "Six",
                            ids: {
                                id: 6,
                                level: 3
                            },
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Seven",
                            ids: {
                                id: 7,
                                level: 3
                            },
                            children: []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my function:

```
findObj(obj, id) {
    if(obj.ids.id == id) {
        return obj;
    }
    else if(obj.children.length != 0) {
        for(var i in obj.children) {
            var temp = findObj(obj.children[i], id);
            if(temp != undefined) {
                return temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using recursive approach with a single `forEach` loop.

```js
const data = {"name":"One","ids":{"id":1,"level":0},"children":[{"name":"Two","ids":{"id":2,"level":1},"children":[{"name":"Three","ids":{"id":3,"level":2},"children":[{"name":"Five","ids":{"id":5,"level":3},"children":[{"name":"Eight","ids":{"id":8,"level":4},"children":[]},{"name":"Nine","ids":{"id":9,"level":4},"children":[]},{"name":"Ten","ids":{"id":10,"level":4},"children":[]}]}]},{"name":"Four","ids":{"id":4,"level":2},"children":[{"name":"Six","ids":{"id":6,"level":3},"children":[]},{"name":"Seven","ids":{"id":7,"level":3},"children":[]}]}]}]}

function findObj(obj, id) {
  let result = null;

  if (obj.ids.id === id) result = obj;
  if (obj.children) {
    obj.children.forEach(c => {
      if (!result) result = findObj(c, id)
    })
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(findObj(data, 6))
console.log(findObj(data, 5))
console.log(findObj(data, 1))
```

Comment: The code works, although I did a few changes to it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

How about using Recursive function like this

```js
function findObj(obj, id) {
    let answer
    if(obj.ids.id == id) return obj
    findChildren(obj.children, id)

    function findChildren(children, id) {
        for(let i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
             if(children[i].ids.id === id) return answer = children[i]
             findChildren(children[i].children, id)
        } 
    }
    return answer
}
```

Comment: The code didn't work but I think this gave me ideas on my other functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I like to separate out the object traversal from the code that is trying to find something.  I would further separate out a generic `deepFind` function using a predicate from the details of your objects.

```js
function * traverse (obj) {
  yield obj;
  for (let child of obj.children) {yield * traverse (child)}
}

const deepFind = (pred) => (obj) => {
  for (let node of traverse (obj)) {
    if (pred (node)) {return node} 
  }
}

const findById = (targetId) =>
  deepFind (({ids: {id}}) => id == targetId)

const objs = {name: "One", ids: {id: 1, level: 0}, children: [{name: "Two", ids: {id: 2, level: 1}, children: [{name: "Three", ids: {id: 3, level: 2}, children: [{name: "Five", ids: {id: 5, level: 3}, children: [{name: "Eight", ids: {id: 8, level: 4}, children: []}, {name: "Nine", ids: {id: 9, level: 4}, children: []}, {name: "Ten", ids: {id: 10, level: 4}, children: []}]}]}, {name: "Four", ids: {id: 4, level: 2}, children: [{name: "Six", ids: {id: 6, level: 3}, children: []}, {name: "Seven", ids: {id: 7, level: 3}, children: []}]}]}]}

console .log (findById (5) (objs))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here `traverse` does a preorder traversal of your object (root first, then branches).  It should work on any object with `children` array properties.  (If these can be optional, it would be trivial to fix this up.)  We write `deepFind` on top of that, taking a predicate and returning the first node that matches it, or `undefined` if none does.

Then `findById` is almost trivial.  We just call `deepFind` with a predicate that checks your id condition.

I like this style of calling it like `findById (5) (objs)`.  I find it clarifies many things.  But if you prefer to call `findById(objs, 5)`, then we can use this instead:

```js
const findById = (obj, targetId) =>
  deepFind (({ids: {id}}) => id == targetId) (obj)
```

Whenever you need a process that you want to stop on first match, generator functions become very useful.