# How to find the target object inside an unknown object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

There is a variable called 'gltf.scene'.

There are many many children inside children.

```
gltf.scene.children[a].children[b]......children[unknown]
```

The children num is unknown without using console.log.

One of my target children name called 'the answer'

Can I found the children by using the array method in javascript?

The target children location is likely as below:

```
console.log(gltf.scene.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[6].children[0].children[3].name) //the answer
```

I search from stack:
[Find an object inside an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66517828/find-an-object-inside-an-object)

However, there is unknown children layer of my case.

Comment: So, you're having to search the entire hierarchy of children to find an object that as a specific name. Is that correct?

Comment: Please clarify your question. You obviously need a recursive iterator for your problem, but without knowning how you select the correct child for your `answer` variable, there's no way to correctly answer your question.

Comment: How do you identify the `answer`? Is it the last only child with the `name` property? Please add a sample of the input to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a recursive function to find it

```js
const findKeyWithName = (data, name) => {

  return  data.children.reduce((res, d ) => {
    
    if(res){
      return res
    }
    if(d.name === name){
     return d
    }
    
    return findKeyWithName(d, name)
  
  }, undefined)

}

const example1 = {children: [{name: 'the answer'}]}
const example2 = {children: [{name: 'not the answer', children: [{name: 'the answer'}]}]}
const example3 = {children: [{name: 'not the answer', children: [{name: 'not the answer2', children: [{name: 'the answer'}]}]}]}

console.log(findKeyWithName(example1, 'the answer'))
console.log(findKeyWithName(example2, 'the answer'))
console.log(findKeyWithName(example3, 'the answer'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the child nesting is too deep, recursion will cause a stack overflow. An alternative is to use iteration:

```js
function findNode (propertyName, value, initialNode) {
  const stack = [initialNode];
  while (true) {
    const node = stack.pop();
    if (!node) throw new Error('Node not found');
    if (node[propertyName] === value) return node;
    for (const childNode of node.children ?? []) stack.push(childNode);
  }
}

const gtlf = {
  scene: {
    children: [{
      children: [{
        children: [{
          children: [
            { children: [] },
            {
              children: [
                { children: [] },
                { children: [{}] },
                {
                  children: [{
                    children: [{
                      children: [{}],
                      message: 'you found me',
                      name: 'the answer',
                    }],
                  }],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        }],
      }],
    }],
  },
};

const result = findNode('name', 'the answer', gtlf.scene);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function.

I borrowed the object in the question you linked, but the solution works regardless of the number of children or the depth of the nesting.

```js
const test = { name: "One", ids: { id: 1, level: 0 }, children: [ { name: "Two", ids: { id: 2, level: 1 }, children: [ { name: "Three", ids: { id: 3, level: 2 }, children: [ { name: "Five", ids: { id: 5, level: 3 }, children: [ { name: "Eight", ids: { id: 8, level: 4 }, children: [] }, { name: "Nine", ids: { id: 9, level: 4 }, children: [] }, { name: "Ten", ids: { id: 10, level: 4 }, children: [] } ] } ] }, { name: "Four", ids: { id: 4, level: 2 }, children: [ { name: "Six", ids: { id: 6, level: 3 }, children: [] }, { name: "Seven", ids: { id: 7, level: 3 }, children: [] } ] } ] } ] }

function findChild(obj, field, value) {
  if (obj[field] === value) return obj
  for (let child of obj.children) {
    const result  = findChild(child, field, value);
    if (result) return result
  }
}

console.log(findChild(test, 'name', 'Seven'))
```